# What is the Time and Space Complexity of this code

Tags: python, arrays, time-complexity, space-complexity

What is the Time and Space complexity of this code (Find Uniques and duplicates)?

```
arr = [1,1,1,2,4,2,5]
a = []
d = []
for i in arr:
    if i not in a:
        a.append(i)
    elif i in a:
        d.append(i)
print(a)
print(d)
```

Comment: Please reformat the code

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through `arr`, which makes complexity `O(N)`. Then you check if `i` is in `a`, which adds another N operations. This makes your overall complexity `O(N^2)`.
Memory complexity is `O(N)`, because you take N elements and distribute them between 2 arrays. You don't create any new elements.

Also a small note: consider using `else` instead of `elif i in a`, because in this case they mean basically the same thing.